# Strange black background behaviour in ionic/angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have just updated my app to ionic 5 and angular 9. I was hoping that this problem will disappear with the new version but it still persists. The issue is that in my app all are pages transitioning with a black screen before the real page comes in. So the user would see for like some millisecond a black screen, what really does not look nicely. Now with the new version things got even worse. In some pages I also experience the black boxes in the ion-refresher area or when opening the keyboard. As well when opening the new modals(in some its working properly in some not) But with the modals the black background even stays behind the modal. I really have no idea why this is happening. I also don't know if code helps here because its actually the same in both modals or also for refreshing content. I have made two pictures of an correct working modal and one with the black background.

I appreciate any help and if you need further code, let me know!

further code:

working modal:
html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button color="medium" (click)="dismiss()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title color="medium">
      Privacy Policy
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="legal-content">
<p> ... </p>
</ion-content>
```

ts:

```
  async showPrivacyModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: PrivacyPolicyPage,
      presentingElement: this.routerOutlet.nativeEl,
      swipeToClose: true
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

buggy modal:
html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="end">
            <ion-button color="medium" (click)="dismiss()">
              <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title color="medium">
       Black BG
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

</ion-content>
```

ts:

```
  async openFilter() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: FilterPage,
      presentingElement: this.routerOutlet.nativeEl,
      swipeToClose: true
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

Here the pictures:

[image: normal]

[image: black bg bug]

Comment: So, is the issue that it goes black before new content shows? or the gap on the modal?

Comment: @Jeff it is actually both, I just could do a screenshot for the transitioning. This in the picture is the issue with modals. But its everything with those stupid black boxes:(

Comment: The way the question is now, I think only someone who has this exact problem can help. Can you post some code here? My guess with the gaps is some padding or margins on the modal, but I can't tell.

Comment: I have added the code. And is not a css problem, since I deleted all css, issue was still there:/

Comment: @Jeff I actually found out that this "black screen bug" is only occurring when the app is on a tabs page and navigates or loads a module. When there is no tab-bar below everything works fine.